# ggplot2: overlay scatterplots with subsets of the same data

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay

I want to produce a facetted scatterplot with ggplot for each scatterplot contains the entire dataset in one colour, with a single ID (of that same dataset) in a different colour on top of the whole scatter. This is the data:

```
**trajectories**

X    Y    ID
2    4     1
1    6     1
2    4     1
1    8     2
3    7     2
1    5     2
1    4     3
1    6     3
7    4     3
```

I use the following code to produce scatterplots for each ID:

```
ggplot(trajectories, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap( ~ ID)
```

How can I print each of these scatterplots on a scatterplot of the whole dataset?

Comment: you mean you need 1 plot. then why are you facetting? remove `facet_wrap(.)` and use `geom_point(aes(colour=ID))`

Comment: No, I do need the facetting because i want a separate plot for each ID, however for each of those plots I also wish to have the entire data set plotted (for example in black) so that I can instantly see how my individual ID's (for example in blue) are related to the entire dataset.

Comment: you mean for each facet, you need the whole plot, but within each facet you need the points for that ID to be coloured differently?

Comment: indeed, so that i get a scatterplot for each individual ID, combined with the entire dataset. 

In this case it would thus give me three scatterplots, that each have a scatter of the whole dataset 'on the background' and with only the scatter of a single ID printed on the whole scatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
ggplot(trajectories, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
  geom_point(color = ID)
```

This will create a scatterplot with a color for each ID. If you want a scatter plot with just one color, just leave out the `color = id` bit.

To shade areas of a certain id, you can draw some inspiration from here:

[How can I overlay two dense scatter plots so that I can see the outlines of each in R or Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706825/how-can-i-overlay-two-dense-scatter-plots-so-that-i-can-see-the-outlines-of-each/9711024#9711024)

It basically calculates a convex hull around subgroups and draws a polygon around it.

Comment: This is not what i meant, What i want is to give the entire dataset one colour in a scatter plot (black), which has an overlay of the scatterplot of a single ID (blue). And this combined scatterplot of the entire dataset with a single ID i want repeated for every ID.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of is to replicate the data set 3 times and set alternate ID for colours and a separate group for facetting. Assuming your `data.frame` is `df`

```
df$ID  <- NULL
df$ID1 <- rep(1:2, c(3,6))
df$ID2 <- c(2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
df$ID3 <- rep(2:1, c(6,3))
require(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var=c("X", "Y"))
df.m$grp <- gl(3, 9)
df.m$value <- factor(df.m$value)

ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = value)) + 
       facet_wrap(~ grp) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "black"))
```

[image]

Note that you have similar points within different groups and so some colours for that group are overwritten by the colour for the next group. For ex: (1,6) should be blue in the first facet but there is a (1,6) in ID=3 which therefore replaces blue to black.

Comment: The only other option I was thinking of was to make three separate graphs and then use `grid.arrange`.

Comment: @joran, yes, of course. If `facetting` isn't an absolute necessity, `grid.arrange` comes in handy!

Answer (score 1):

In base plots you can do something like:

```
  par(mfrow=c(length(unique(ID)),1))
    for(i in unique(ID)){ plot(X,Y,col=as.numeric(ID==i)+1)}
```

[image]

If overplotting was a problem you can add jitter() or transparent colors.